# Python regex help :)?

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, mitmproxy

I'm trying to match, last letter in string 'onlin' as any and then replace it if it matches with word offline. No luck. Please give advice, cheers.

```
import mitmproxy
import re

def response(flow):
    old = b'Onlin\w{1}'
    new = b'Offline'
    flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace(old, new)
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove that `’` character in `Onlin\w{1}’`?

Comment: It got in there by accident, doesn't help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you explain what the expected output is?

Comment: In flow.response.content.replace value of variable 'old' is replace by value of the variable 'new'.  Im trying to use regex to match value of variable old with the last character as wildcard. But it doesn't work. Basically 'onlin' + [a-z, 0-9]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are using the wrong function for replacement. Try `re.sub`.

```
def response(flow):
    old = b'Onlin\w'
    new = b'Offline'
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub
    flow.response.content = re.sub(old, new, flow.response.content)
```

Comment: Works very well, cheers, I'm quite new to this

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace()` does not recognize regular expressions.

To perform a substitution using a regular expression, use re.sub().

The pattern `Onlin.` matches any string that starts with Onlin and ends with any character.

```
import re

old = re.compile('Onlin.')

def response(flow):
    new = 'Offline'
    flow.response.content = old.sub(new, flow.response.content)
```

Example:

```
>>> old = re.compile("Onlin.")
>>> old.sub(new, "Onlin Onlina Online")
'offlineoffline offline'
```

Comment: This did not work, but thank You for your time.